# Is this sentence correct? ( on a table or on the table)

Tags: articles

> There is a book on a table.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
What is the image of this sentence?

Should I write “on the table” instead of “on a table?”

What’s the difference?

Answer (score 0):

> There is a book on a table

It says that any random book is on any random table.
The article **a** is used to represent common nouns. Therefore, this sentence represents randomness in terms of both table and book.

Let's take the other case

> There is a book on the table

Here, the book is still a random object but the table is being specified. The article **the** specifies a proper noun. Here, a table is chosen and being used.

If you want to specify the table, you should go with *the*.For the other case, just carry on with *a*.

The only difference is specification. You specify, or more accurately, pinpoint at an object by using *the*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book on the table.
The first answer said 'the' is used with proper nouns.  It is used with common nouns
.  Proper nouns are the names of people or places and are always capitalized.  It is possible to use the article 'the' with a proper noun.  The first that comes to mind is the Liberty Bell.  However, most proper nouns are the names of people or places, and neither would be preceded by an article. 
     John Henry was a fictional character.
     New Jersey is next to New York.
Some people have trouble telling if a proper noun is a thing or a place.  Ask yourself if it is an object.  The Brooklyn Bridge is a proper noun and it is considered a thing, not a place, so we use 'the".  Brooklyn itself is a place, so we do not use an article with it.

The difference in usage of "the' and "a' is specificity. Let us say someone has just moved into an apartment with some furniture.  The new resident says to a friend, "I have everything I need except a table."  He is not speaking of a specific table.
     His friend replies, "Would the table in my spare room fit?"  Now the friend is speaking of a specific table, the one in his spare room, so he uses 'the".